# onserverclick event not working using html builder in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I am using anchor tag and I want to fire event on click anchor tag.But unfortunately it is not working . Here is my code :

```
html.Append("<a id='dltTag'  class='ca_quy_e' runat='server' onserverclick='Delete_Click'>");
            html.Append("<i class='fa'>");
            html.Append("</i>");
            html.Append("</a>");

protected void Delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      //My code
}
```

Every thing working perfect like table is forming , but only onserverclick not working.

Comment: is that work for you ?? got detail you want ??

Comment: It is not working . I a want to fire event on click anchor tag

Comment: so you mean to say there is no button control called delete you just want to call serverside method ..am i correct , if i am correc than you dont need method with this paramter (object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: Exactly I have no button control . I have anchor tag and I want to delete some data from server side when I click anchor tag

Comment: so remove parameters from method that is not needed and confusing too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make use of javascript or jQuery i.e. clientside scripting for calling serverside method from client side

a. create method with wemethod attribute

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string IsExists(string value)
    {
        //code to check uniqe value call to database to check this
        return "True";
    }
```

b. register client call with element

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
          if (!IsPostBack)
               txtData.Attributes.Add("onblur", "focuslost()");
     }
```

c. make use of jquery Ajax

```
function IsExists(pagePath, dataString, textboxid, errorlableid) {

$.ajax({
     type:"POST",
     url: pagePath,
     data: dataString,
     contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
     dataType:"json",
     error:
          function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
               $(errorlableid).show();
               $(errorlableid).html("Error");
          },
     success:
          function(result) {
               var flg = true;
               if (result != null) {
                    flg = result.d;
                    if (flg == "True") {
                         $(errorlableid).show();
                    }
                    else {
                         $(errorlableid).hide();
                    }
          }
     }
    });
}
function focuslost() {
     var pagePath = window.location.pathname + "/IsExists";
     var dataString = "{ 'value':'" + $("#<%= txtData.ClientID%>").val() + "' }";
     var textboxid = "#<%= txtData.ClientID%>";
     var errorlableid = "#<%= lblError.ClientID%>";
     IsExists(pagePath, dataString, textboxid, errorlableid);
}
```

if you are not getting than here is full article : [Calling Server Side function from Client Side Script](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/400719/Calling-Server-Side-function-from-Client-Side-Scri)

if you are using scriptmanager than you can use this [Execute server side code from JavaScript using Script Manager](http://blog.goodcoresoft.com/asp-net-execute-server-side-code-from-javascript-using-script-manager/)

---

you need to use `_dopostBack` for psotbacking to server or make use of ajax to call server side method

Read: 
[Usage of doPostBack in a Real Environment](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/jaishmathews/doPostBack01292006042750AM/doPostBack.aspx)

Example

```
html.Append("<a id='dltTag'  class='ca_quy_e' runat='server' onclick='DoPostBack()'>");
            html.Append("<i class='fa'>");
            html.Append("</i>");
            html.Append("</a>");

function DoPostBack() 
{
  __doPostBack('DeleteButton','');     
}
```

Comment: You wrote __doPostBack('DeleteButton',' ' ); . what is 'DeleteButton' here i think 'dltTag ' will be here.

Comment: @farhanfarhan - DeleteButton is delete button control in your interface ..you can check the url in the post

Comment: @farhanfarhan - check the answer as this is the only way to achieve the things...